# Cannot find module (in a VPS)

Tags: node.js

Recently i ordered a VPS debian 9 cloud and wanted to put a small test project on there made in nodeJS, on a local pc it works fine but when i transfer it over and try to run it it gives me this error.

```
module.js:557
throw err;
^Error: Cannot find module './models/info'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/root/Server_files/index.js:5:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:617:3
```

the code that gives errors when run on the cloud is this one below.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const Broutes = require('./routes/Broutes');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Info = require('./models/info');
const BodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
mongoose.connect("###");
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));


app.use('/', Broutes);



app.post('/Info/add', (req,res)=>{
let info = new Info();
info.Name = req.body.Name;
info.Address = req.body.Address;
info.Email = req.body.Email;
info.save((err,info)=>{
if (err){
  console.log(err);
} else{
  res.redirect('/');
}
})
})

app.listen(3000, (req, res)=>{
console.log('server started on port 3000');
})
```

as i already said this code works just fine on a local computer but when on the VPS it starts spitting out this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats probably because you are missing a file/module. 
In this line:

> **const Info = require('./models/info');**

You have required an `info.js` file which is in the `models` folder in your **root directory**, but according to nodejs, that file doesn't exist. Just confirm that it's there and your code will run as normal.

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive :-)